# Comparing HTTP and FTP for performance

Tags: http, ftp, network-programming

We need to setup a server that needs to receive files from about 1000 locations simultaneously. The file will be pushed every 5 mins from all the locations. 
The file size will be about 10kb.
We have the option to receive the file via HTTP or FTP. What would be more optimum in terms of performance and reliability ?

What kind of server configuration would be required to handle this? We are planning to host this on Amazon EC2.

Are there any optimizations we can do on the server to handle this?

Answer (score 2):

FTP has a more complicated session establishment with a lot of roundtrips.

HTTP also makes it easier to add encryption and compression.

Ideally, you would use HTTP with persistent connections.

Also, it would scale better if the 1000 locations don't all send at once but instead are evenly spread over the 5 minute interval. Then I think the requirements would be quite low.